# fsockopen(): unable to connect to remote server ip Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3, remote-server, fsockopen

I would like to ask what is something missing or what is wrong with my fsockopen() in codeigneter. I`ve been searching for fives days now and I couldn`t figure out what is wrong since others who got the same error with mine we are on a different scenario. While them are for sending emails me is to get the Server Status if online or offline.

I`ve been creating a Online Games Web Templater were it can fetch/display data from Game Remote Server to webhosting. I was able to connect MSSQL to a remote server but the fsockeopne() does not work.

Helper.php Codes

```
function getServerConnection($ip, $port) {
    $sockres = @fsockopen($ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 0.01);
    if (!$sockres) {
        return '<b class="text-danger">OFFLINE</b>';
    } else {
        @fclose($sockres);
        return '<b class="text-success">ONLINE</b>';
    }
}
```

View Codes

```
<p class="m-b-10">
<span class="left">LOGIN: <?php echo getServerConnection($server_settings->server_ip, $server_settings->login_port) ?></span> 
<span class="float-right">WORLD: <?php echo getServerConnection($server_settings->server_ip, $server_settings->server_port) ?></span></p>
```

Var_dum $sockres and error

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: fsockopen():
> unable to connect to 192.168.1.1:80 (Connection timed out) - JUST
> DUMMY IP. IT HAS A REAL REMOTE IP Filename:
> helpers/myhelper_helper.php
>
> bool(false) int(110) string(20) "Connection timed out"

The **allow_url_fopen = on** and remote **server firewall** has been configure already

Thank you in advance :) sorry for my English I am not really good on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figureout this error it was because I am using wrong port. and make sure you configure correctly into your windows firewall. And try to use this one to check the port https://ping.eu/port-chk/